# Как подружить js и php

Tags: php, javascript

есть яваскрипт для постройки по точкам и есть пхп код выдергивания значений из базы постгрес. нужно передать массив с данными из кода пхп в код яваскрипта

Comment: php: `echo json_encode($array)`
на js используйте ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывайте JS кодом необходимый php скрипт, которые выдергивает данные из базы, после чего выдает результат в json. И обрабатывайте данные на js

```
<?php
//Берем данные из базы
echo json_encode($data);//$data - данные которые надо вернуть в js
?>
###################
#Код JS
$.get('/export.php',function(data){
      //Построение графика, все данные которые вернул сервер хранятся в data
})
```

Небольшой шаблон кода.

PS js- с использованием jquery

Comment: Спасибо огромное. но вот дело такое - первый день просто работаю с яваскриптом и пхп, вообще не в зуб ногой как говорится. следующий вопрос наверно наивен до ужаса - сделал как написали 
  $.get('/ara.php',function(data){
      document.write(data);  
})
выдает дикую дрянь типа псевдотекста и в конце числа мои. как поправить? вот что показывает https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8SBzylZ-emOakNGTnZvclV1Ukk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: вы это, зачем еще данные-то выводите ? у вас видимо картинка на сервере строится...

если вы строите ее js, то надо не выводить картинку, и вот так парсить.
`$.get('/export.php',function(data){},"json")`

а если вам просто картинку показать :) то просто присвойте какому нить элементу img src вашего php скрипта :)

Comment: ну так у меня массив элементов. я и хочу посмотреть в каком виде они хранятся. просто при выводе (смотреть ссыль), вначале идет псевдографика али хз че там, а потом мои данные, вот их я и хочу загнать в массив

Comment: спасибо всем кто помогал, разобрался с псевдографикой - нужно было хедер имедж пнг убрать.